# How to display a message box prompting the user to insert a next disk in Visual Studio Setup project?

Tags: visual-studio, installation, setup-deployment

I'm working on a Visual Studio Setup project which consist over 10Gb Cab File. My question is: How can I publish this project on the two disk and display a message box prompting the user to insert a next disk?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a native "Microsoft way" to do this but `InnoSetup` supports that feature and I use `InnoSetup` for all my setup projects including VS projects. I usually use silent installation for VS packeges. You can use `InnoSetup` to split your VS setup into pieces and after merging them at installation time, VS setup can be triggered.

Check this link: http://www.dateiliste.com/en/source-code/17-inno-setup/57-how-to-split-up-large-files-with-inno-setup.html